# flutter list.sort doesnt give result

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, dart

I have a list which I get from firestore called "allResults", this list looks kind of like this:

`resultList= [{createdAt: Timestamp(seconds=1630015336, nanoseconds=0), UserID: crGDzZU7nrNoz0EIHoT4AcMrRre2}, {createdAt: Timestamp(seconds=1630101736, nanoseconds=0), UserID: crGDzZU7nrNoz0EIHoT4AcMrRre2]`

I am trying to sort this list by the `createdAt`Timestamp with the following code:

`resultList.sort((a, b) => a["createdAt"].seconds.compareTo(b["createdAt"].seconds))`

Problem is that by program just doesnt spit out anything after I call this sorting, kind of like its sorting forever and cannot get out. I dont get an error message but also no result, and any command I run after the sorting one just doesnt get executed.

Does anybody see the error in my sorting code?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example that demonstrates the problem?  Or at least show the code where you try to "spit out anything after this sorting"?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that in your post, you gave an example of the contents of `allResults`, but you are trying to sort another list called `resultList`. However, if they are the same type try this:

```
resultList.sort((a, b) => (a["createdAt"] as Timestamp).seconds.compareTo((b["createdAt"] as Timestamp).seconds))
```

Or this:

```
resultList.sort((a, b) => (a["createdAt"].toString() ).compareTo(b["createdAt"].toString()))
```

And when you defined your `allResults` list, declare it as:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> allResults
```

Comment: Ah yeah, its true that I mixed up ```allResults``` and ```resultList```, those are basically the same thing and cannot be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I tried all of them but didnt get a good result, however now it gives me ```null``` as the output instead of nothing at all so i guess thats some kind of progress ^^.